# How to run Elasticsearch 6 on an Apple Silicon Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, elasticsearch, apple-silicon

For developing an application, I need to run Elasticsearch 6 on an Apple Silicon Mac.

I've tried to run it with Docker. Reading [Docker Desktop for Apple silicon](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/), I've installed Rosetta2 with:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

And added the `--platform linux/amd64` command line option.

Running:

```
docker run -d --platform linux/amd64 --name elasticsearch  -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:6.8.18
```

I obtain the warning about the [AVX instruction set](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions.html):

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseAVX=2 is not supported on this CPU, setting it to UseAVX=0
```

So I added the command line option : `-e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-XX:UseAVX=0"`, but I still obtain:

```
[2021-08-22T00:06:20,727][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [unknown] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 131, exit value: 1
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 131, exit value: 1
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 131, exit value: 1
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Spawner.spawnNativeController(Spawner.java:118) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Spawner.spawnNativeControllers(Spawner.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 131, exit value: 1
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1109) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Spawner.spawnNativeController(Spawner.java:118) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Spawner.spawnNativeControllers(Spawner.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.18.jar:6.8.18]
    ... 6 more
```

Then I look at [Machine learning settings in Elasticsearchedit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ml-settings.html)
, where it states:

> Machine learning uses SSE4.2 instructions, so it works only on machines whose CPUs support SSE4.2. If you run Elasticsearch on older hardware, you must disable machine learning (by setting xpack.ml.enabled to false).

So I added the command line option: `-e"xpack.ml.enabled=false"`, Elasticsearch now starts but nothing appears in the log and it doesn't answer to requests.

My question is: How to run Elasticsearch 6 on an Apple Silicon Mac ?

Comment: Note, for version 7, though it’s not currently linked from [the install docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html), you can change the `x86_64` to `aarch64` in the URL and download an ARM version , e.g., [`https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.2.0-darwin-aarch64.tar.gz`](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.2.0-darwin-aarch64.tar.gz)

Answer (score 10):

I just had this issue, i worked out that you can run elasticsearch using the curl instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/getting-started-install.html), but wanted to use docker.

If you want to use [my image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/tompreston377/elasticsearch/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated), go ahead:

```sh
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 tompreston377/elasticsearch
```

To make this image, I organized files like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile-elastic
└── elasticsearch.yml
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile-elastic.yml
FROM arm64v8/openjdk:8-jdk-buster

WORKDIR /usr

# add a non root user
RUN useradd -m elasticuser

# Download extras
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y curl nano

# Download elasticsearch
RUN curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.8.23.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf elasticsearch-6.8.23.tar.gz

# Add config
ADD elasticsearch.yml /usr/elasticsearch-6.8.23/config/elasticsearch.yml

RUN chown -R elasticuser: .
USER elasticuser

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-18/bin/java
ENV discovery.type=single-node
ENV xpack.security.enabled: false
ENV xpack.ml.enabled: false

RUN cd elasticsearch-6.8.23/bin
RUN chown -R elasticuser: elasticsearch-6.8.23

EXPOSE 9200 9300
CMD cd /usr/elasticsearch-6.8.23/bin/ && ./elasticsearch
```

elasticsearch.yml:

```
# elasticsearch.yml
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.ml.enabled: false

http.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Commands:

Build: `docker build -f Dockerfile-elastic -t elastic .`

Run: `docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elastic`

Answer (score 6):

This is generally not supported, but [there is a report](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/69767) that https://hub.docker.com/r/webhippie/elasticsearch/ might work.

If you didn't have a good reason to upgrade yet, maybe running it on M1 might help? Native support (without Rosetta) [has been added in 7.12](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/67103).

Comment: `webhippie/elasticsearch` worked for me. Thank you! the latest version of ES that this image has is v6.4.0

Comment: @Armin, did you have to do anything special to get webhippie to work? I'm having issues getting elasticsearch 6 running on my M1 laptop. Getting the same i/o exception error when it starts up, even after removing docker volumes and rebuilding.

Answer (score 3):

Im struggled with this problem for a long time and here is what i found:

- Regular version 6 or 7 does not work.
- For version 7 you need to use
  `docker.elastic.co/webhippie/elasticsearch:7.10.2-arm64`
- For version 6 `webhippie/elasticsearch:6.4`

I hope this information is useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [github issue #81383](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/81383#issuecomment-988145990)

Adding `-e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"` fixed the crash with `7.16.1`.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I myself faced this problem and could not fix it for a long time. Solution with For version 6 `webhippie/elasticsearch:6.4` also works.

I was able to start the container `elasticsearch:6.8.6`
And that's what i did

1. Add to es environment `- xpack.security.enabled=false` and `- bootstrap.system_call_filter=false`;
2. Remove from es `volumes`.
3. Add `esdata` to common `volumes`

Like this

```
 es:
    image: elasticsearch:6.8.6
    environment:
        - xpack.security.enabled=false
        - discovery.type=single-node
        - bootstrap.system_call_filter=false
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"

volumes:
    esdata:
    <--anything else-->
```

Maybe this solution can help someone

Comment: This didn't work for me. :-(

Comment: I use `docker-compose.yaml`. Please show your file.
And what is the error in the console?