# Kibana server is not ready yet(Mac m1)

Tags: docker, macos, elasticsearch, search, kibana

I trying to use docker container :elastic search and kibana. \But keep face to this word "Kibana server is not ready yet", when I connect to the web (http://localhost:5601/)

my system:

- Mac m1 os
- docker version : 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b

Below is my yaml file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.2
    platform:linux/amd64
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.1
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://es01:9200"]
    depends_on:
      - es01
    networks:
      - elastic
    
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

docker ps -a : looks fine. 
I have no idea what is wrong. 
please let me know.

Comment: Where are nodes es02 and es03? The cluster cannot be bootstrapped without them

Comment: Hello, and I tried to do adding es02, es03.But localhost:9200  connection returns "safari is busy.....", and localhost:5601 returns "Kibana server is not ready yet"

Comment: This is because of the version. working effectively image version was 7.15.0. And this answer was helpful--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754654/unable-to-launch-the-elastic-search-on-apple-mac-chip-m1-using-docker.